# Keras not importing

Tags: python, tensorflow

import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<ipython-input-30-64156d691fe5>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
```

> File "E:\Users\Rajesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 22, in 
>      from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
>
> File "E:\Users\Rajesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>
> File "E:\Users\Rajesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "E:\Users\Rajesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>    File "E:\Users\Rajesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>    File "E:\Users\Rajesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>    File "E:\Users\Rajesh\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>    File "E:\Users\Rajesh\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Comment: Make sure you have cudNN and CUDA compatible with tf version

Answer (score 0):

Is it keras or tensorflow ?

for making both work, uninstall both

```
conda remove tensorflow
conda remove keras
```

Remove it from local env as well

```
python3 -m pip uninstall tensorflow
python3 -m pip uninstall keras
```

From global env too

```
sudo python3 -m pip uninstall tensorflow
sudo python3 -m pip uninstall keras
```

Then do

```
python3 -m pip install tensorflow==1.8.0 --user
```